# Use of passive filter in oscilator circuit

Tags: microcontroller

I see on datasheet of a part that I want to use in my next design that is common to use an passive componente, like an inductor or capacitor, to avoid EMI issues in oscilator circuit.

Here is the datasheet:
[image]

So, my question is:
1 - What value of capacitor shoud I put in there? There is some calculation avaiable to design it?
2 - I have notice that many schematics come with an inductor in that place. Is that rigth?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Having **any** component in series with one of the crystal input pin (XI) is quite uncommon. I have never seen that before. You should indicate what **IC** it is that you are using. Include a link to its datasheet. I do not see how adding a component like C4 would help in improving the crystal oscillator. I have designed on-chip crystal oscillator so I do have some experience with this.

Comment: Odd that this component is in "XI", (likely oscillator input) rather than "XO" (oscillator output?). Many oscillator application notes suggest a series component, such as http://www.ti.com/litv/pdf/szza043  Mostly it is a resistor, but where crystal frequency is high, can be a small capacitor, roughly equal to C2,C3.

Comment: Is this for establishing a range of phase-shifts, to ensure the Barkhausen Criteria is met?

Comment: Please provide a link to the datasheet for the part.

Comment: https://www.nxp.com/webapp/Download?colCode=FXTH871XD&Parent_nodeId=1427704241608725899181&Parent_pageType=product this is the part datasheet..

Answer (score 0):

EMI issues are separate from resonance tuning error and crystal uW power limits.

C4 might affect all 3. I suggest using a series 1k R instead, or nothing if you don't care and just want a clock.

### Details

The crystal is a 3rd order resonator acting as a parallel resonant bandpass and not a series mode. if you search for *[my RLC impedance nomograph](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A17574%20rlc%20nomograph)* you can understand the impedance vs RLC for the crystal model and shunt caps added like 10pF and perhaps come to the conclusion that all you need is a series R like 1k to attenuate square wave harmonics while not reducing the fundamental using RC just below the operating point. This also reduces crystal power absorption of harmonic power as many are limited to 10uW.

Normally an unbuffered CMOS inverter builtin has at least a linear gain of >>10 but you can verify for your chip by increasing the R until itfails to oscillate due to the Barkhausen criteria.  ( and Gain>>1 for stable starting oscillation to full square wave)  Using a 10pF scope probe instead of a load cap you can scope the square wave input after R4 in place of C4. An inductor of same impedance may shift the frequency but yield 2nd order atenuation of crystal currents for extreme reduction to EMI egress froma square wave driving a tiny cap in a loop.